# use android universal image loader

Tags: android, picasso

please i am making that changes picture for the url and i have a problem..... the image does display what i want is not the picture should change depending ont the list item i click..... it work when i use the r.drawable.image....... but not working when i try to use the getimage  url and it is not working....  i used the universal-image-loader-1.6.2.jar  and it iis giving me errors...... this is my code.......... and NOTE THAT artp is the url of a picture that i saved in the databse and it is coming from anoder class...

this is my code

```
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.DisplayImageOptions;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoaderConfiguration;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Music extends Activity{

    TextView name,song,album,about;
    String nam,son,albu,abou;
    ImageView picc;
    Button listen, download;
    public int  newInt;


    MainActivity maa = new MainActivity();

     Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

       String artp = extras.getString("artp");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stu
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.music);
        name= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        song= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.song);
        album=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.album);
        about=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.about);
        picc=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.picc);
    listen=(Button) findViewById(R.id.listen);
        download=(Button) findViewById(R.id.download);
        settext();


    }
    private void settext() {
         Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
           newInt= extras.getInt("man");

           String abt = extras.getString("abt");
           String son = extras.getString("son");
           String alb = extras.getString("alb");
           String art = extras.getString("art");

           String abt2 = extras.getString("abt2");
           String son2 = extras.getString("son2");
           String alb2 = extras.getString("alb2");
           String art2 = extras.getString("art2");

               if(newInt==0){
           name.setText(art);   
           song.setText(son); 
           album.setText(alb); 
           about.setText(abt);
            listen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Intent ner = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://media.takserver.in/Hamid/Music/1391/11/25/Imagine%20Dragons%20-%20Night%20Visions/Imagine%20Dragons%20-%20Night%20Visions/004-imagine_dragons-demons.mp3"));
                    startActivity(ner);
                }
            });
            download.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Intent ner = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://media.takserver.in/Hamid/Music/1391/11/25/Imagine%20Dragons%20-%20Night%20Visions/Imagine%20Dragons%20-%20Night%20Visions/004-imagine_dragons-demons.mp3"));
                    startActivity(ner); 
                }
            });
                                    // Get singletone instance of ImageLoader
                        ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
                        // Initialize ImageLoader with configuration. Do it once.
                        imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(this));
                        // Load and display image asynchronously

                        DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                                    .showStubImage(R.drawable.ic_launcher) //this is the image that will be displayed if download fails
                        .cacheInMemory()
                        .cacheOnDisc()
                        .build();

                        imageLoader.displayImage(artp, picc, options);
               }        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Picasso**](http://square.github.io/picasso/) allows for hassle-free image loading in your application—often in one line of code!

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

Many common pitfalls of image loading on Android are handled automatically by [**Picasso**](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

- Handling ImageView recycling and download cancelation in an adapter.
- Complex image transformations with minimal memory use.
- Automatic memory and disk caching.

[image]

Comment: please i also what the image to load in a list item view different images instead of the r.drawable.... how do i do it .......

Comment: images are in drawable folder? if it is than....make an array of it              '   int[] images = {R.drawable.my,R.drawable.gh.....}'

Answer (score 1):

First you can't perform this operation before `onCreate()` method.

```
 MainActivity maa = new MainActivity();
 Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
 String artp = extras.getString("artp");
```

Also you can't instantiate your Activity. So just move these line in `onCreate()` method.

```
  Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
  String artp = extras.getString("artp");
```

Also make `String artp` global variable and after that on `onCreate()` retrieve as

```
   Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
   artp = extras.getString("artp");
```

Comment: thank you it is no more giving me errors but it is failing to load the right image on the image view it is just loading the R.drawable.ic_launcher not the image of the web addresss... can you help me